# Getting running scriptname in prolog

Tags: swi-prolog

Is there some way in prolog (SWI-Prolog) that I can get the name of the executing script just like the **FILE** in perl or arg[0] in C ?

I read the docs and I see nothing about this.. the docs actually dont give much support with anything and have very few examples :/

thanks for any help.

Comment: See the comments to the previous question with the swi-prolog tag.

Comment: @Boris it didn't help much :/ still cant figure out how to do it

Comment: `current_prolog_flag(argv, Argv)` will give you the command line arguments used to invoke Prolog http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=current_prolog_flag/2

Comment: @Boris: seems that your comment could be the answer.

Comment: @Boris but then how is it printed? I'm just getting error messages..

Comment: Comment on my answer; show what you are doing and your error messages. Google.

Answer (score 0):

`current_prolog_flag(argv, Argv)` will give you the command line arguments used to invoke Prolog, http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=current_prolog_flag/2

Answer (score 0):

The `argv` flag suggested by @user1812457 will not include the script filename, so what you need to do instead is to get both `os_argv` and `argv` and then look at the difference. I used:

```
script_name(Name) :-
  current_prolog_flag(argv, Argv),
  current_prolog_flag(os_argv, OsArgv),
  append(Os, Argv, OsArgv),
  last(Os, Name).
```